# Disabling Samsung TTS term expansion

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-speech-api

It appears that Samsung's text-to-speech engine for Android automatically expands certain terms that appear in spoken strings. For example, if a Samsung user has Samsung's TTS engine selected, which I believe is the default, a string like "20 A" is spoken as "20 ampere". Is there a way to disable that "feature"?